# blackberry 6-7 environment failed at WL.Client.connect

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

i create a fresh new worklight (5.0.6) project with jquerymobile (1.2.0), add the blackberry 6-7 environment, nothing else.
here is the wlcommoninit code.

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.Client.connect({
            onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
            onFailure: onConnectFailure
    });
}
function onConnectSuccess(){alert("ok");}
function onConnectFailure(){alert("ko");}
```

i get the following issue when i preview the app.

```
wlclient init started worklight.js:1118
before: app init onSuccess worklight.js:1118
Request [/apps/services/api/cm2/blackberry/init] worklight.js:1118
after: app init onSuccess worklight.js:1118
wlclient init success worklight.js:1118
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) 
`http://localhost:8080/apps/services/api/cm2/blackberry/init`
[/apps/services/api/cm2/blackberry/init] failure. state: 403, response: undefined worklight.js:1118
```

the common environment works fine.
am i missing something ?
thanks for your help

Comment: how did you run this application on device. Can you please us out by providing the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known defect when previewing the BlackBerry 6-7 (and also Windows Phone); there is improper handling of the 403 status response (it's OK to get it, but the handling mishandles it...).

The app should work correctly on an actual device (probably simulator as well).